# Ubuntu 14 with kerberos authentication, nslcd still needed?

Tags: authentication, ldap

I have converted my Ubuntu 14.04.1 systems over to kerberos authentication using corporate AD servers.  The instructions said to install `sssd`, `libpam-sss`, `libnss-sss`. These package installations would change the pam setup to enable krb5 authentication.

I copied over my fully functioning sssd.conf files from my centos environment.  My `sssd.conf` file sets up my ldap connection config, my krb5 realms.  I also copied over my fully functional `/etc/krb5.conf`. After I added the packages, the nsswitch.conf file looked like:

```
passwd  compat ldap sss
group   compat ldap sss
shadow  compat ldap
```

My question is, since I'm using `sssd` I would have thought that nslcd functionality was no longer needed.  But if I shut that service down I am unable to login.  When I login, I do get a kerberos ticket.  I just find it odd that I need `nslcd`. Can anyone explain how this is supposed to work?

Does the `nsswitch.conf` file look correct?  I would have thought ldap would no longer be needed as the `sssd` handles all of that.  At least that's how its handled on centos.

I'd welcome anyone to clear the air for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
passwd  compat sss
group   compat sss
shadow  compat 
? for nsswitch.conf
```

`ldap` is for `nslcd`

Then `sssd` is preferably for Fedora and `nslcd` for Ubuntu

Comment: I apologize for the long delay. sssd needs providers to provide authentication, id etc.. Since this isn't a pure AD setup, as in no keytab file etc.. this Kerberos setup uses LDAP to find the uid/gid username and the rest of the users information. So LDAP part is needed, and the Kerberos part is simply to satisfy the actual password portion.  And this works, so I think I answered my own question. Both SSSD and nslcd is needed.  Another issue is now users cannot change their passwords, and when notified that their password has expired, the user has to login to a windows system to change it. ugh